# adding <setBody> value dynamically in apache camel configuration

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel

I am trying to send request to webservice using camel for that i have declared camel-config.xml as below

```
<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <!-- incoming requests from the servlet is routed -->
        <from uri="servlet:hello" />
        <choice>
            <when>
                <!-- is there a header with the key name? -->
                <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
                    <constant>POST</constant>
                </setHeader>
                <header>advertisement</header>
                <setBody> <simple>{"id":"k"}</simple> </setBody>
                <!-- yes so return back a message to the user -->
                <to
                    uri="cxfrs:http://xxxxxxxxx:8080/xxx/rest/xxx/xxxxxx" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <!-- if no name parameter then output a syntax to the user -->
                <transform>
                    <constant>Add a name parameter to uri, eg
                        ?name=image_xx.xx
                    </constant>
                </transform>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </route></routes>
```

Here I'm setting values as static can anybody say how to set values to `<setBody></setBody>` dynamically which I'm sending through a HTML form as a POST request

Comment: Why don't you create a processor and extract the values there and set them to the body?

Comment: i am very new to this apache camel. Can u share some code so that i can understand easily

Comment: The simple language has a number of functions for dynamic values: http://camel.apache.org/simple.

Comment: What dynamic value(s) do you need to set in <setBody>? What is it from the servlet request you need to access and use?

Comment: yes, from servlet request only i need to access and for your information i have not created any servlet class

Answer (score 0):

you can write anything into body using javascript+java (see my example)

```html
...
...

    <setBody>
        <javaScript>
            var m = new java.util.HashMap();
            m.put("aField", <<<Here java code!>>>>);
            m.put("anotherField", <<<Here another java code!>>>>);
    
            m;
        </javaScript>
    </setBody>
    <marshall ref="json" />
    <to uri="....... "/>
...
...
```

The map will be parsing into a json string!
Kings regards

FabryProg

Comment: sorry but i am not using any javascript here and also i am getting data from html page.

Answer (score 0):

i searched and found that

```
 <setBody>
        <simple>${in.headers.advertisement}</simple>
    </setBody>
```

this is working fine